# Dealing with dates and timezones in a python project

Tags: python, datetime

In a side project I have to manage, compare and display dates from different formats. What's the best design strategy to follow?

I planned:

1. All dates are parsed according their
   format and stored in the db in
   9-tuple python format using UTC
2. When I have to do calculations and
       compares I transform 9-tuple in
       datetime object (using UTC). If I
       have to store back some date
       calculation I use again 9 tuple
       format
3. On user interface time is
       display converting from UTC to
       user's timezone

Have you any feedback about this strategy?

Comment: Why aren't you using `datetime`?

Comment: Related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-timezone-best-practices

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the DB's native datetime format rather than this "9-tuple" format. It'll make queries easier, and it's probably more space-efficient too.

Shouldn't be too hard to convert from that back into a Python datetime object. You can use the `dateutil` module if you're having trouble.

I think you're right about keeping a consistent timezone throughout the DB though, and the convert it to the user's timezone when you need to.

Comment: sorry it is an object database. I store directly python objects